# pygame platform collisions

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a platformer in pygame, to learn the engine.

I have it creating multiple instances of the block, and I have a player object that can fall at increasing speed. How can I make it so that when the player hits the block, it doesn't fall through? Here is my code:

```
#imports
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

#init game
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,480))
pygame.key.set_repeat(True) 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#classes
class playerClass:
    x = 100
    y = 100
    boundingBox_x = 32
    boundingBox_y = 32
    sprite = pygame.image.load("Image2.png").convert_alpha()

class Block(object):

    sprite = None

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        if not Block.sprite:
            Block.sprite = pygame.image.load("Image1.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = Block.sprite.get_rect(top=y, left=x)

#objects
playerObject = playerClass()
blocks = []
blocks.append(Block(0, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(1*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(2*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(3*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(4*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(5*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(6*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(7*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(8*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(9*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(10*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(11*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(12*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(13*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(14*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(15*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(16*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(17*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(18*32, 14*32))
blocks.append(Block(19*32, 14*32))

blocks.append(Block(0, 13*32))
blocks.append(Block(19*32, 13*32))
blocks.append(Block(0, 13*32))
blocks.append(Block(19*32, 13*32))
blocks.append(Block(0, 12*32))
blocks.append(Block(19*32, 12*32))
blocks.append(Block(0, 11*32))
blocks.append(Block(19*32, 11*32))
#colors
white = 255,255,255

#variables
up = False
down = False
right = False
left = False

xspeed = 0
yspeed = 0
gspeed = 0.2
#functions

#main loop
quitting = False
while quitting == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():

#event processing
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quitting = True

#game logic
    yspeed += gspeed
    playerObject.y += yspeed
#drawing
    screen.fill((white))

    screen.blit(playerObject.sprite,(playerObject.x,playerObject.y))
    for block in blocks:
        screen.blit(block.sprite, block.rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

#ending
    clock.tick(60)
```

Also, I am aware that I am using a lot of code to build the level. I am working on a system to read the level out of a txt file. Thanks for

Comment: If you use the [`pygame.sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) module, it can do most of the hard work for you. If you just use images and try to do it all yourself, there's more work to do. Which answer do you want?

Comment: As a side note, it looks like you've got a different serious problem with your code: You're using class attributes rather than instance attributes for almost everything. This means that all instances of the class will share the same value. You usually don't want to use class attributes except for things like constants or global behavior flags.

Comment: @abarnert: Okay. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "fixing this"? Switching to pygame.sprite? Doing collision detection manually with just plain images and coordinates? Changing the class attributes into instance attributes?

Comment: @abarnert: I have the rest figured out, but need help with changing the class attributes to instance attributes

Comment: That's really a separate question, and there are lots of dups here… but the short version is: Instead of writing `x = 100` under `class playerClass:`, write `self.x = 100` instead its `def __init__(self):` method.

Comment: You can do `blocks = [ Block(i*32, 14*32) for r in range(4) ]`

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is to use the [`pygame.sprite`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) module, which is designed for exactly this kind of thing.

The example on that page shows most of what you want to do; the [Shooter](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40s%40h%40shooter-HEAD%40Shooter.py/) sample that comes with pygame shows all the details.

But briefly: Make `Block` and `Player` both subclasses of `sprite.Sprite`, put all the `Block`s into a sprite group instead of just a list, and use `spritecollideany(player, block_group)`, and that's all there is to it.

---

If you want to do it manually, it's not *that* much harder. You need to keep track of the bounding rect for the player the same way you do for each block, and then instead of this:

```
spritecollideany(player, block_group)
```

… you do this:

```
player.rect.collidelist([block.rect for block in blocks]) != -1
```

In general, everything `sprite` does, you can do yourself—just in about twice the code. And of course you have to figure out all the things you need to do—with `sprite`, the simple API for sprites and groups pretty much tells you all the things you to do with them in most games.